# Como fazer uma matriz correr dentro de outra utilizando funções?

Tags: c, matriz

Tenho duas funções, uma pertence a uma matriz 10x10 e a outra, a uma matriz 3x3. Preciso fazer a matriz 3x3 correr dentro da matriz 10x10.

Como faço isso?

Desde já agradeço quem puder ajudar.

Exemplo: essa é a matriz 3x3:

```
void conv(int p[3][3]){
    int i, j;
    for(i=0;i<3;i++){
        for(j=0;j<3;j++){
            p[i][j]=p[i][j]*p[i][j];
        }
    }
}

void img(int mat[lin][col]){
    int i, j, contador=1;
    for(i=0;i<lin;i++){
        for(j=0;j<col;j++){

        }
    }
}
```

Preciso que a função conv, que tem uma matriz, seja inserida na função img, onde há outra matriz. Eu preciso que ela percorra em todos os elementos da matriz img alterando o valor original.

Comment: Defina "pertence à matriz" e "correr dentro da outra", por favor.

Comment: Exemplo: essa é matriz 3x3: 

void convulacao(int p[3][3]){
 int i, j;
 for(i=0;i<3;i++){
  for(j=0;j<3;j++){
   p[i][j]=p[i][j]*p[i][j];
  }
 }
}

Preciso que ela passe por uma função onde há uma matriz2 10x10 e ande 1 índice a direita, alterando cada um dessa matriz2

Comment: Logo abaixo da pergunta, existe o botão `editar`. Use-o para postar os códigos você escreveu. Ficará mais fácil para compreendermos o problema.

Comment: `p[i][j]=p[i][j]*p[i][j];` - isso vai apenas substituir cada elemento da matriz pelo valor de seu quadrado.

Comment: Não sei se entendi direito. Percorrer uma matriz 10x10 e extrair pedaços 3x3 é fácil. Mas o que você quer fazer com esses pedaços 3x3?

Comment: Ok, acho que entendi. Vou tentar formular uma resposta.

Comment: Eu editei a pergunta.. na verdade é um código um pouco extenso, eu precisava mesmo fazer uma matriz correr dentro da outra.. só abreviei o código para facilitar..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extrair um trecho 3x3 de uma matriz 10x10 e passá-lo a uma função tem algumas complicações. A primeira é que em matrizes, todos os elementos são armazenados na memória sequencialmente. Ou seja, em uma matriz 10x10 temos os 100 elementos em sequência. Em uma matriz 3x3, vamos ter os 9 elementos em sequência. Entretanto, em uma matriz 3x3 dentro de uma 10x10, os 9 elementos desejados da 3x3 não estarão em sequência, e portanto não podem ser simplemente representados sob a forma de um ponteiro simples, o que exige uma técnica mais elaborada.

Além disso, há ainda alguns problemas referentes que o processamento de uma submatriz pode acabar interferindo no processamento de uma outra submatriz quando os elementos da matriz são alterados. Por exemplo, imagine que você tenha a seguinte matriz (vou usar 5x5 para ficar mais fácil o entendimento):

```
A B C D E
F G H I J
K L M N O
P Q R S T
U V W X Y
```

Se ao processar a submatriz ABC-FGH-KLM, você substituir o G por um Z, a submatriz subsequente será BCD-**Z**HI-LMN ao invés de BCD-**G**HI-LMN.

Há várias possíveis soluções para esse problema. Acho que a solução mais simples para esse problema seria:

- Representar a submatriz como índices da matriz principal.
- Usar duas matrizes diferentes, uma para a leitura de dados e outra de rascunho para a escrita. No final, a matriz de rascunho pode ser copiada por cima da original e então descartada, ou então a original ser descartada e manter-se a resultante.

Se eu entendi direito, você quer uma função que receba uma outra função como parâmetro, a fim de aplicá-la sobre toda a matriz. Em linguagens de programação orientadas-a-objetos e com tipos genéricos tais como C++ e Java, isso é muito mais fácil de se fazer. Isso também é algo possível no C, mas com uma sintaxe assustadora. Eis o resultado:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void conv(int largura, int altura, int linha, int coluna, int original[altura][largura], int resultante[altura][largura]) {
    int i, j;
    if (linha >= altura - 2 || coluna >= largura - 2) return;
    for (i = linha; i < linha + 3; i++) {
        for (j = coluna; j < coluna + 3; j++) {
            resultante[i][j] = original[i][j] * original[i][j];
        }
    }
}

void operar(int largura, int altura, int original[altura][largura], int resultante[altura][largura], void (*op)(int largura, int altura, int linha, int coluna, int original[largura][altura], int resultante[altura][largura])) {
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < altura; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < largura; j++) {
            op(largura, altura, i, j, original, resultante);
        }
    }
}

void imprimir(int largura, int altura, int original[altura][largura]) {
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < altura; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < largura; j++) {
            printf("%5d ", original[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main() {
    int entrada[5][5] = {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {6, 7, 8, 9, 10}, {11, 12, 13, 14, 15}, {16, 17, 18, 19, 20}, {21, 22, 23, 24, 25}};
    int saida[5][5];
    operar(5, 5, entrada, saida, conv);
    imprimir(5, 5, entrada);
    printf("\n");
    imprimir(5, 5, saida);
}
```

[Veja aqui funcionando no ideone.](http://ideone.com/dNnj0a) Eis a saída gerada:

```
    1     2     3     4     5 
    6     7     8     9    10 
   11    12    13    14    15 
   16    17    18    19    20 
   21    22    23    24    25 

    1     4     9    16    25 
   36    49    64    81   100 
  121   144   169   196   225 
  256   289   324   361   400 
  441   484   529   576   625
```

Observe que a função `conv` é quase a mesmo que você deu. A diferença é que a largura e a altura da matriz estão explicitadas nos parâmetros da função bem como a linha e a coluna do bloco 3x3 a ser operado. Também há duas matrizes, sendo uma a que será lida e outra onde será escrita.

A função `operar` é a mais assustadora e tem uma assinatura horrorosamente longa e complicada. Em especial o `void (*op)(int largura, int altura, int linha, int coluna, int original[largura][altura], int resultante[altura][largura])` é um ponteiro de função. O `void` é o tipo de retorno da função. O `(*op)` indica que isso trata-se de um ponteiro de função chamado `op` e o conteúdo depois disso corresponde aos tipos de parâmetros dessa função. O código dentro da função `operar` no entanto é bem simples, ele apenas percorre as matrizes chamando à função `op` em todas as posições.

Por fim, na função `main` temos isso:

```
operar(5, 5, entrada, saida, conv);
```

Isso significa que a função `conv` deve ser executada para cada posição das matrizes 5x5 `entrada` e `saida`. Desta forma, você pode codificar outras funções similares à `conv`, desde que tenham os mesmos parâmetros e o retorno `void` e utilizá-la na função `operar` desta mesma forma.

Ah, e uma observação importante. Isso só tem sentido se você realmente precisar de submatrizes na sua função `conv` ou semelhante. Caso você esteja trabalhando elemento por elemento sem que o processamento de um elemento interfira no outro, tudo isso ficaria muito mais simples. No momento, a sua função `conv` poderia ser reescrita assim:

```
void conv(int largura, int altura, int linha, int coluna, int original[altura][largura], int resultante[altura][largura]) {
    resultante[linha][coluna] = original[linha][coluna] * original[linha][coluna];
}
```

Comment: Obrigada pela explicação Victor! Vou tentar aplicar isso na resolução do meu problema. Assim que eu finalizar, insiro aqui.